# How to customize full toast size in android

Tags: android, toast

I am showing a customized toast, with a background image of some creature, but i want the toast to be of my  defined size.

It was not possible in normal toast by using this:

```
View view = toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.go);
toast.setView(view);`
```

Then i used layout inflater like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hit_toast,
                                    (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout));
     layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.go);
     TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToShow);
     // Set the Text to show in TextView
     text.setText(msg);

     Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
     //toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
     toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     toast.setView(layout);
     toast.show();
```

and my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_toast_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#DAAA"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textToShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="ll"
        android:textColor="#00ffff" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

But still the size of toast is same just position is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried changing size thats width and height. But it seems you can never show a toast with width and height specified... Toast change their shape according to the contents,say background image or text inside them.... 
This is true for default toast provided in android.

Instead of doing this you can always make a small layout named `toast_layout` and set its visibility as INVISIBLE. Create this in the same layout file you want to show it. Put it anywhere you want your toast to appear.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/toastbackground"
        android:visibility="invisible" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toast_img"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/man" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toast_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/down_img"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#00ffff"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Create a tweenAnimation file inside res/anim folder named `fade_in_out` here unlike normal toasts you can customise the fadein and fadout property as  as you like.

Then call the below function when you want to show the toast inside activity like:-

```
clone_toast(R.drawable.image,"Yao it Works...");

void clone_toast(int ids, String msg) {
        toast_img.setImageResource(ids);
        toast_text.setText(msg);
        toast_layot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        toast_layout.startAnimation(fade_in_out);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to customize your toast, then [SuperToast library](https://github.com/JohnPersano/Supertoasts) is the answer.

It's flexible yet limitless in term of customization!